# Плагины unity и как их изменить

Tags: unity3d

Я имею плагин [DiscordUnity](https://github.com/DiscordUnity/DiscordUnity), который работает очень коряво, однако я знаю как его починить. Но при импортировании его как пакета все мои изменения не сохраняются, да и импортируются не 4 папки с большим количеством вложенных файлов, а только 4 файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать, как мне отредактировать библиотеку и импортировать вместе с изменениями

Comment: Заметил что при сборке в vs в bin -> debug появляются те самые файлы. Остаётся только понять как те самые файлы заменить. Попробую ручками, если получится отпишусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается изначально плагин надо собрать (да ладно), в VS studio это делается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после чего в bin\Debug (Или Release если вы собирали как релиз)\netstandard2.0 (или что вы там используете) появятся два файла Name.dll и Name.pdb где Name название вашего решения. Потом импортируем этот плагин в unity и два одноимённых файла заменяем на свои.